Ax = b and inverse matrices
Consider two questions from a Linear Algebra textbook:
1. Solve $A \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}$ for three special cases of $\mathbf{b}$:
$$
A \mathbf{x}_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, \quad A \mathbf{x}_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, \quad A \mathbf{x}_3 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}.
$$
If $\mathbf{x}_1, \mathbf{x}_2, \mathbf{x}_3$ are the columns of a matrix $X$, what is $A X$?
2. Given the solutions from 1:
$$
\mathbf{x}_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}, \quad \mathbf{x}_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}, \quad \mathbf{x}_3 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix},
$$
solve $A \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}$ for $\mathbf{b} = (3, 5, 8)$. Additionally, find matrix $A$.
For 1, it's straightforward: if we define $X = [\mathbf{x}_1 \ \mathbf{x}_2 \ \mathbf{x}_3]$, then $A X = I$.
For 2, given $\mathbf{b}$, I initially assumed that
$$
A \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 5 \\ 8 \end{bmatrix}, \quad A \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 5 \\ 8 \end{bmatrix}, \quad A \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 5 \\ 8 \end{bmatrix},
$$
which leads to the equation
$$
A \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 3 & 5 & 8 \\ 3 & 5 & 8 \\ 3 & 5 & 8 \end{bmatrix}.
$$
However, this gives an incorrect $A$. The correct solution shows $\mathbf{b} = (3, 5, 8)$ leads to $\mathbf{x} = 3 \mathbf{x}_1 + 5 \mathbf{x}_2 + 8 \mathbf{x}_3 = \begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 8 \\ 16 \end{bmatrix}$. What am I missing here?

If $AX=I$ then you can show that $XA=I$ so to solve $Ax=b$ you premultiply by $X$ to get $x = Xb$.

Your premise that $Ax_1, Ax_2, Ax_3$ all equal the same $b$ is wrong.  That's where your attempt went off the rails.

Question #2 was phrased in a rather terse way that allows for some ambiguity in interpretation.  The critical omission is that there should be a break in the sentence just before "solve $Ax = b$ when $b = (3,5,8)$", separating it entirely from the earlier "If" clause.  The hypothesis is supposed to be that these are the specific values from Question #1, retaining the right-hand sides $[1, 0, 0]^T, [0,1,0]^T, [0,0,1]^T$.  Then that assumption gives you enough information about $A$ to also solve $Ax=b$ for the given $b$.

Understanding the Matrix $X$
In question 1, the matrix $X$ is formed by the columns $\mathbf{x}_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$, $\mathbf{x}_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$, and $\mathbf{x}_3 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$:
$$
X = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}.
$$
Solving $A X = I$
We know that $A X = I$, so $A = X^{-1}$.
The inverse of $X$ is:
$$
X^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ -1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}.
$$
Thus, $A = X^{-1}$.
Solving $A \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}$
Given $\mathbf{b} = \begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 5 \\ 8 \end{bmatrix}$, the solution to $A \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}$ is obtained by:
$$
\mathbf{x} = X \mathbf{b}.
$$
Now, compute $X \mathbf{b}$:
$$
X \mathbf{b} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 5 \\ 8 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 3 + 5 \\ 3 + 5 + 8 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 8 \\ 16 \end{bmatrix}.
$$
Thus, the solution to $A \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}$ is:
$$
\mathbf{x} = \begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 8 \\ 16 \end{bmatrix}.
$$
